# If $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, $r \le x+y$, then $\exists a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a\le x$, $b\le y$ and $r=a+b$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

This is a small lemma that I am using in a larger proof.  It is not complex, but I want to make sure I am not overlooking something that causes this argument to fail.

**PROOF**

Let $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $r \le x+y$, where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.
Choose $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a\le x$ and $x-a\le x+y-r$.  This $a$ exists, since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. between every two elements of $\mathbb{R}$,  $\exists$ an element of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $b=r-a$.  Then $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $-r=-a-b$.  Thus $x-a\le x+y-r = x+y-a-b$.  This implies that $b\le y$.

Therefore, for $r\in\mathbb{Q}$, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, if $r\le x+y$ , it is possible  to find $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}, a\le x, b\le y$ , such that  and $a+b=r$.

Comment: The proof is correct

Comment: @bravoralph Thank you.  I thought so, but it actually took me a bit to reach that, so I wanted to make sure.